# Php scope question (referencing a function inside of another function)

Tags: php

I have the following code:

```
function process_bulk_action() {
        if (isset($_GET['locations'])) {
                $location_ids = ( is_array( $_GET['locations'] ) ) ? $_GET['locations'] : array( $_GET['locations'] );
                global $wpdb;

                switch ( $this->current_action() ) {
                    case 'edit':
                         bulk_edit($location_ids);
                    break;
                    case 'delete':
                        bulk_delete($locations_ids);
                    break;
                    default:break;
                }
        }
    }

    function bulk_delete($ids) {
        foreach ( $ids as $id ) {
            $id = absint( $id );
            $sql = "DELETE FROM wp_nc_location WHERE location_id = $id";
            $delete = $wpdb->query( $sql );
        }
    }

    function bulk_edit($ids) {
        foreach ( $ids as $id ) {
            $id = absint( $id );
            $sql = "SELECT name FROM wp_nc_location WHERE location_id = $id";
            $select = $wpdb->query( $sql );
            echo 'select: '. $select. ',';
            print_r($select);
        }
    }
```

However I am getting the following error message when I try to call either bulk_edit or bulk_delete from inside that switch statement above:

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined function bulk_delete
```

I realize I am getting something wrong with the scope but I'm not sure where to put the functions bulk_edit or bulk_delete...

Comment: Are you inside a class with this?

Comment: @Matt it's being called from within another function, so all are defined before called, unless there's code or includes we aren't seeing

Comment: Is this all of your code? You likely have a missing or additional bracket somewhere.  @Matt - Functions can be defined below the actual reference to them in the file. The code is compiled before execution

Comment: Also the functions won't actually be declared in the *local* scope.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm guessing from your use of `$this->` in various places that those functions belong to a class? In this case, you have to call the function like... `$this->bulk_delete(..arguments..);`